# Download zip file on google drive

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage, google-drive-picker

I want to create a MERN stack application from where I can auth to google drive, upload files and download zip folders. But I want to upload files in unzip format and when I want to download folder from google drive I want similar behaviors as google drive does i.e: It first zip the folder and the  download it.
I checked it's documentation various npm modules but I am not able found and figure out how to do it.
Any one can help me in this

Comment: Currently I am doing R&D on it checking possibility.

Comment: In your goal, what language do you want to use?

Comment: @Tanaike I am using Nodejs as backend and react as frontend and for storage using Google Drive, as nodejs is good for handling IO operations

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, I think that there are 2 directions. In 1st direction, the files are downloaded with the information of the folder structure and those are zipped with Node.js. In another direction, when Node.js requests to Web Apps created by Google Apps Script, and the files in the folder are zipped with Web Apps and the zip file is returned. But in this case, the maximum zip file size is 50 MB because of the specification of Google side. If those were not useful for your situation, I apologize.